# Use value as a key (JOLT)

Tags: json, jolt

I've a JSON:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
   //here another keys
   ...  
  "events_retargeting_groups": [
    {
      "id": 38207945,
      "value": [
        24,
        25
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 38207944,
      "value": [
        25
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get this result:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
   //here another keys
   ...  
  "events_retargeting_groups": {
    "38207944": [
      25
    ],
    "38207945": [
      24,
      25
    ]
  }
}
```

I need all `keys` from source JSON, but I want to modify `events_retargeting_groups`. Value from `id` should be a key and values from `value` are values for this key. Any ways to do this modification with JOLT?

**UPDATE**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "events_retargeting_groups": [
      {
        "id": 57913131,
        "value": [
          12
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "events_retargeting_groups": [
      {
        "id": 38207945,
        "value": [
          24,
          25
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 38207944,
        "value": [
          25
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // the elements other than "events_retargeting_groups" object 
      "events_*": {
        "*": {
          "value": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&4.@(3,id)[]" // &4 copies the key "events_retargeting_groups" 
                                  // after going 4 levels up the tree to grab that
                                  // need to traverse 3 levels up the tree in order to get
                                  // the value of the related "id"  
                                  // [] is needed for the array of single component            
            }     
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Update** : To perform this case, you might expand by adding `[&5].` identifier to the innermost part of the "events_retargeting_groups" object and `[&1].` to the else case ( eg. `"*": "&"` ) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "events_*": {
          "*": {
            "value": {
              "*": {
                "@": "[&5].&4.@(3,id)[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What if there will be multiple elements in JSON? Inside array [ { element 1 }, {element 2}, etc]. I tried to put your code into `"*": { ... code }`, but now result stores inside arrays, like `"id" : [ 1, 2 ]`

Comment: well, I've just updated the question @takotsubo